# Filter Number from string in c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need to Filter the number after a particular word in a string. For example

(CaseId : 200908005485) Test WTest3 ==> require the number **200908005485**

[CaseId : 200908005486] Test WTest ==> require the number **200908005486**

Note : CaseId can be at any position in the string.

```
    private string GetObjectIDFromSubjectWithCustomExpression(ItemType itemType, string subject, string expression)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(expression))
            return null;
        //[Case ID:678878],   [Case ID:#ObjectId#]

        string exp = GetFieldNameFromExpression(expression);

        var pattern = expression.Replace("#" + exp + "#", "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]");
        if (subject.Contains('('))
        {
            pattern = expression.Replace("[", "(").Replace("]", ")").Replace("#" + exp + "#", "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]");
            pattern = pattern.TrimEnd();
        }
        var rx = new Regex(pattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (rx.IsMatch(subject))
        {
            var collection = rx.Matches(subject);
            if (collection.Count > 0)
            {
                var matchedstring = collection[collection.Count - 1].Value;
                Regex re = new Regex(@"\d+");
                Match m = re.Match(matchedstring);
                if (m.Success && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Value))
                {
                    exp = m.Value;
                    return exp;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Tried this and it is working, but I would like a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: what about slitting string with `:` as a delimiter, like `expression.Split(":")[1]`

Comment: define "more efficient", please? efficient in terms of what?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann efficient in the way that it can be a 6 digit number or a 13 digit number. It can vary.

Comment: @that_guy_jrb that's in no way _efficiency_, but a specific way of increased functionality.

Comment: also, [this page of the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions) will probably answer your question

Comment: by efficient you mean shorter code? more readable?

Answer (score 2):

CaseId : 200908005485) Test WTest3 ==> require the number 200908005485

[CaseId : 200908005486] Test WTest ==> require the number 200908005486

To get the CaseId from above lines, create a regex patten like this "CaseId : ([0-9]*)". here the () helps to get the sub match group i.e the number from the match object.

Here the [0-9] matches any number between 0-9 and * makes it to match n number of times.

If the number is of specific lenghth just change pattern to "CaseId : ([0-9]{lenght of the number})". here the {} helps to match the number only to the specified length and if the number is of more than the specified length the remaining will be ignored by the regex match.

Use this site for testing and learning more about regex https://regex101.com/